# Java IntelliJ not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have a github project where I solve Project Euler just for fun. I was getting rid of some old metadata and I think I broke it...now I can't seem to get it working in IntelliJ, because I deleted the bin with the class files (I believe its still pointing there, instead of generating new ones?!)

https://github.com/amilner42/projectEuler.git

That is the github project, if you could clone it and get it working in IntelliJ and tell me how you did that that would be awesome :D

Here is the error I get:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: problems40to49.Problem44
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes I have, it does nothing :/

Comment: How are you trying to run the project?

Answer (score 1):

There is neither IDE's metadata nor `pom.xml` on github, so the best way to go is to create new project and copy contents from `src` folder to created one.
Then right click on `Problem44.java` and select `Run Problem44.main()`
Should work.